# Does exporting everything from DLL affect performance

Tags: windows, performance, dll

To do unit testing I had to export many small, internal classes which were never intended for consumption by the clients of my DLL.

I know that each exported function results in a stub in executable image and that Windows loader has to perform fix-up on those stubs if DLL is not loaded at its preferred location.

Someone suggested building DLL as a static lib, solely for the purposes of unit testing.

I wonder if it is worth the trouble? I could find no reference to how significant a problem of exporting every class from DLL may be, or is there any significant gain in loader performance and memory consumption if I am selective about it.

I think I read somewhere that GCC compiler exports everything by default.

***EDIT***: since the stated motivation for the question is disputable, let me rephrase it:
Should I go through my DLLs and remove DLLEXPORT on all classes that are not exposed to its clients? Let's say I am working with a bunch of legacy DLLs and I noticed they have a lot of unnecessary exports. Will that improve the speed of loading? Specifically on Windows 7 and 8 using MSVC version 9+.

Comment: It is a code smell.  If the only way you can detect that your code failed is by having access to internals, how could the regular client programmer ever detect it?  Or you are just testing the wrong thing, only ever test what a client programmer will use, the public api.

Comment: @HansPassant We are doing TDD - building from bottom up and the requirement by the management is that every layer of code has to have a set of unit tests, even if it is not directly exposed to the clients. In fact, we don't know exactly what will the final public API be.

Comment: Unlikely to create a measurable loss of performance.  But you can always try it and see.  It should also be easy enough to set things up so that only the debug build contains those exports.

Comment: @Harry Johnston In simple tests with one DLL and about 100 vs 200 exported functions I get so much variability in load times, I can't attribute it to anything specific. The real scenario that I may have, where there are about 50 DLLs and there may be tens of thousands exports, is too laborious to set up. Thus the question on SO. I think it is unlikely too, but was hoping someone with deeper knowledge of the loader may confirm that.

Comment: If the question is really about 100 exports vs 200, there shouldn't be any issue.

Comment: @SimonMourier No, not really, I had low expectations I would see something in that test. But I am really curious if there is any good reason to trim hundreds of classes which are exported and probably shouldn't be. I think we are talking about tens of thousands exports.

Comment: tens of thousands does look weird :-) I would try to remove them, but it's more an intuition.

Comment: @SimonMourier well, MFC100U.DLL alone is about 14,000+ exports. Nothing to do there if you must use it, but its shows that the number is not unreasonable.

Comment: true, but correct me if I'm wrong, they're all exported by ordinal, so it reduces dll size, and no lookup/string search occurs at binding time. A good article: http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=115

Comment: I doubt that this question could be elaborated and answered because: 1) loading a library and searching for a function to call could differ from compiler to compiler; 2) dll structure and library loader could differ from one version of OS to another. The question is too wide or too specific(has meaning only to a particular platform and environment)

Comment: The obvious "cost" is that your DLL will be larger for two reasons.  First, the linker will not be able to discard any of the member functions of these classes because all of them will be used (ordinarily, it can discard any member functions that are not called or which are fully inlined). Second, the export table will be substantially larger because it'll contain the decorated name strings for all of the additional exports. Larger DLLs consume more address space. I expect that other than the size overhead, there won't be much measurable performance impact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Does exporting everything from DLL affect performance?**

It probably does, however the effect is immeasurably small. I made a python script that creates a test DLL exporting > 50,000 symbols. It consists of 1024 exported classes that each contain 48 functions (16 member functions, 16 virtuals and 16 static functions). The compiler also generates about 4-5 exports for each class that appear to be things like the vtable.

I measured load time of the application using SysInternals ProcMon. The load time on the very ancient underpowered test machine before linking the DLL was between 15-30ms. ***Adding the DLL, and one call to each of the ~50,000 exported functions resulted in no measurable change***.

This is not a completely conclusive test, but it is good enough to convince me that ***the symbol resolution and fix-ups are probably an order of magnitude or more faster than any other limiting factor***.

Interestingly, to be able to create such an insane DLL with the Microsoft tools required adding the /bigobj compiler flag and it appears there is also limit of 64K exported symbols in the PE format of a DLL. Furthermore, the static (compile time) compile and link phases for the DLL and application each took many minutes and used a lot of memory.

So you will be pushing on all kinds of other limits before you get to loader performance problems.

> **Let's say I am working with a bunch of legacy DLLs and I noticed they have a lot of unnecessary exports. Will that improve the speed of loading?**

Nope.

> **Should I go through my DLLs and remove DLLEXPORT on all classes that are not exposed to its clients?**

It depends.

**Not simply because of load performance.** If this was so critical to the application, then presumably somebody would be benchmarking the startup and would know *exactly* where the performance problems were. We shouldn't guess about performance impacts:

> "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil." -- Knuth

**However, there may be other reasons for not exporting those "internal" classes and functions.** The point to exporting a class/function is so that client code can use it. It should match the DLL's logical external API. If that wasn't the case for a function or class, then it shouldn't have been exported. If there is a lot of functionality in internal classes that cannot be used, or tested, without going through the DLL's public API, it makes one wonder why that functionality exists? If the intent was to create generic reusable classes, perhaps they should be in a library of their own?

Test Driven Design doesn't mean you have to go around exposing everything publicly. And DLL exports are not necessarily required for even the most invasive white-box unit testing of a class. For example, the unit test fixture could be built monolithically and statically link (or even directly include the sources) to whatever internal classes are needed.

Conversely, a completely excusable explanation for having done it this way may be simply that it was easy and simple to implement. If everything else is essentially equal (modulo style and some theoretical architecture concerns), it is also poor form to needlessly change and disrupt a system that was already done a certain way and is working fine.

**So this may be a design that should not be copied or extended, and maybe it is worth cleaning it up whenever maintenance or refactoring opportunities come up.**

> **I think I read somewhere that GCC compiler exports everything by default.**

[Mingw LD documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/WIN32.html#WIN32) concurs. Although, note that it says that if you export with __declspec or .DEF files, this auto-export behavior is disabled.

Comment: +1. Thanks for doing the actual test. Could you also publish the timings and/or the test script please so we can reproduce it? Still, it sounds obvious: the bindings are probably in a hash table, so it makes sense that adding methods doesn't add a performance penalty. I'm personally more interested in the overhead of a DLL vs a static lib: from a compiler POV, you can do a lot more optimizations for a static lib than for a DLL. While I agree that this wasn't the question, I wondered if that's easy to test with your current test script?

Comment: You beat me to it! I started doing the same thing. I was also thinking about sending question to Raymond Chen of The Old new Thing, since he likes to dig into these 'old' things. Frankly, I never expected there will be any big effect, but once I posed the question, I was a bit unhappy that it is so hard to get experiment/experience-based or authoritative confirmation. I lost 200 points on my stubbornness, but you did well deserve them.